# Understanding number reversing using loop

Tags: c, loops

i got into this simple program in c programing, the program is simply reversing any input number by user, using a while loop, i dont know if its okay to post such a question but i didnt realy understood how the while loop works

```
int n, reverse = 0;

   printf("Enter a number to reverse\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   while (n != 0)
   {
      reverse = reverse * 10;
      reverse = reverse + n%10;
      n = n/10;
   }

   printf("Reverse of entered number is = %d\n", reverse);
```

i would be so thankfull if anyone could explain it to me

Comment: you already run it and checked that it works?

Comment: Try watching `n` and `reverse` at each step to see what's happening.

Comment: Time to learn how to **use the debugger**

Comment: Or run it through with paper and pen, trying different numbers, such as -123, 5, 0, 100.

Comment: Incidentally, since this is "integer reversing", putting in a number like `100` will result in an output of `1` instead of `001`.  That's fine, but might be important to note.  (You can fix this by tweaking your printf, if necessary.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(condition is true)
{
    // Do stuff.
    // Normally, but not always, the "stuff" we're doing is something that modifies
    // the condition we're checking.
}
```

So in your case as long as the content of `n` is not equal to `0`, you will continue to execute the loop. If `0` is entered in the `scanf()` the loop will be skipped altogether.

At each iteration of your loop you're using the property of integer division to make the value of `n` smaller by a factor of 10. ie:

```
n = 541
n = n / 10 = 541/10 = 54
n = n / 10 = 54/10  = 5
n = n / 10 = 5/10   = 0
```

So `n` will eventually be 0 and the loop will exit.