# Why does this loop work?

Tags: c, loops

I was hoping that someone could explain why this program works. I am a beginner with C.
The program returns the user entered number in reverse.(eg 1234 =4321). If reverse is initialised to zero then why does the 7th line make sense? Sorry about the title, not sure how to ask it.

```
int n, reverse=0, rem;
printf("Enter an integer: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
while(n!=0)
{
 rem=n%10;
 reverse=reverse*10+rem;
 n/=10;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477728/understanding-number-reversing-using-loop?rq=1
This answer was the closest I could find but after using printfs to see what is going on i'm not sure why reverse takes a value at all.

Comment: `reverse=reverse*10+rem;` The first time reverse is set to `rem`, since `reverse*10 == 0`. On subsequent runs, `reverse > 0`, so the line works as expected.

Comment: Why does it make sense to multiply something by zero?!

Comment: The 7th line works because `*` has a higher precedence than `+`. That is, `reverse*10+rem` is evaluated like this: `(reverse*10) + rem`.

Comment: @KerrekSB it makes sense to multiply something by zero if the zero is a variable. It's clearer to write `x = n * a + b` than to write `if (n==0) { x = b; } else { x = n * a + b; }`

Comment: @slim: Yes, I was trying to question the OP's question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is taking advantage of ways of using integer operators % / and * to:

- get the rightmost decimal digit of a number: `1234 % 10 == 4`
- remove the rightmost decimal digit of a number: `1234 / 10 == 123`
- add a digit to the right hand side of a number: `123 * 10 + 4 == 1234`

Using those it repeatedly takes digits off `n` and pushes them onto `reverse`:

```
123 0
12  3
1   32
0   321
```

Step through the code by hand and it should make sense. Take an initial value of n == "123".

```
Is n zero? No, so go into the loop.
rem = n%10 == 123 % 10 == 3
reverse = reverse * 10 + rem == 0 * 10 + 3 == 3
n = n/10 == 123/10 == 12

Is n zero? No, so loop around.
rem = n%10 == 12 % 10 = 2
reverse = reverse * 10 + rem == 3 * 10 + 2 == 32
n = n/10 == 12/10 = 1

Is n zero? No, so loop around..
rem = n%10 == 1 % 10 = 1
reverse = reverse * 10 + rem == 32 * 10 + 1 == 321
n = n/10 == 1/10 = 0

Is n zero? Yes, so leave the loop.
reverse == 321
```

Or, starting again with an input of zero:

```
Is n zero? Yes, so leave the loop.
reverse == 0
```

This program is fairly pointless, but it's worth realising that the same principles work in other bases, like 16 (hexadecimal) and 2 (binary) -- and if you end up doing certain kinds of programming, that will be useful.

Comment: All the answers were great, but the effort you put into yours really helped me understand it, so i'll choose this as the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this step by step.

1. `rem=n%10;` takes the remainder of `rem` divided by 10. In the case of 1234, this means `1234 % 10` is 4.
2. `reverse=reverse*10+rem;` multiples its values by 10 (shifting values to the left, if you will) and then adds `rem`. Since, in the first turn of the loop, its value is 10, we simply add 4, for a result of 4.
3. `n/=10;` is the *integer* division by 10. This means that `1234 / 10 = 123` (any decimals are lost).
4. New turn of the loop! Now, the first line is `rem= 123 % 10;` or 3.
5. `reverse=reverse*10+rem;` is now `reverse=4*10+3;` or 43 (notice the beginning of a pattern here?)
6. `n/=10;` so now `n = 12;`

Repeat steps 4 to 6 for `n = 12` until `n  = 0`. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

If reverse is zero, the value of "reverse * 10 + rem" is simply "rem".

Answer (score 0):

The remainder `n%10` is always the last decimal digit of n, whereas using *integer division* on the line `n/=10` (same as `n = n/10`) the last decimal digit is effectively dropped. So `rem` will become each decimal digit of `n` in turn, starting from the least significant digit. The reverse is constructed by always adding (`+rem`) the digit to the end, while moving the previously added digits one place over to the left (`reverse*10`). Leading zeroes (such as the initial value of `reverse`) have no effect (`0*10 == 0`).

As for why `reverse` is initialised at all: the initial value of un-initialized variables is undefined in C, and thus anything could result out of the first `reverse*10` otherwise. Also, if the user enters `0` as the number, the loop condition is false and the loop body is never run, but the reverse of `0` is then correct (`0`).

Answer (score 0):

```
int n, reverse=0, rem;
printf("Enter an integer: ");
scanf("%d", &n); //read in a number
while(n!=0) //while that number has digits to process
{
 rem=n%10; //find out what's in the 1s place
 reverse=(reverse * 10) + //move our current answer up a position
          rem;            //and then add in the last digit. 
                          // if it's 0 that's the digit we want
                          //so leaving it as is will be fine.
 n/=10;  //chop one digit off. Since integer division
         //truncates this will drop the last digit rather
         //than leave a fraction and always rounds toward 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through each loop as variables values will be as shown,

```
rem = 4
reverse = 0 + 4 = 4
n = 123

rem = 3
reverse = 40 + 3 = 43
n = 12

rem = 2
reverse = 430 + 2 = 432
n = 1

rem = 1
reverse = 4320 + 1 = 4321 
n = 0
```

While loop exits at the end as `n` becomes `0`

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through this with a debugger or using `printf()`s would answer your question, but it's a simple enough program so you could do this with pen and paper (or digital pen and paper)

```
printf("Enter an integer: ");
scanf("%d", &n);   // so say the number is 103
while(n!=0)        // n=103 so we enter the loop
{
 rem=n%10;               // rem = 3
 reverse=reverse*10+rem; // reverse = 0*10 + 3 = 0 + 3 = 3 
 n/=10;                  // n = 103/10 = 10
}
```

The line `n/=10` works because of [integer division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers) 
the line `rem=n%10` works because of [modulus operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html). 
this line: `reverse=reverse*10+rem` works because of [Operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence), Multiplication (`*`) has a higher precedence than Addition (`+`) so it will be done first. This isn't C specific, it's the same in [basic mathematics](http://www.webquest.hawaii.edu/kahihi/mathdictionary/images/PEMDAS.png).

So now `n==10` and `reverse==3`, 10 is still not 0 so the loop continues:

```
 rem=n%10;               // rem = 0
 reverse=reverse*10+rem; // reverse = 3*10 + 0 = 30 + 0 = 30 
 n/=10;                  // n = 10/10 = 1
```

So now `n==1` and `reverse==30`, 1 is still not 0 so the loop continues:

```
 rem=n%10;               // rem = 1
 reverse=reverse*10+rem; // reverse = 30*10 + 1 = 300 + 1 = 301 
 n/=10;                  // n = 1/10 = 0
```

So now the loops stops because `n==0` and the reverse has `301` which is the reverse of the given input `103`